# bootstrap not working in laravel 5.6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I tried adding a navigation bar to my laravel version 5.6 project but it doesn't add styles and nor JS

[image]

**my code :**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LSAPP</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="/services">services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Check console log and show the error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Considering you have a fresh laravel app you can add on your head

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and at the end of your body

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

to use the Laravel css and javascript boilerplate.

**Remember that Laravel 5.6 uses Bootstrap 4.0, so you need to use its syntax:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LSAPP</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/services">Services</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Check the component documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/).

Also bair in mind that the default Laravel assets have more stuff than only JQuery and Bootstrap.